# How to create conditional columns in Pandas Data Frame in which column values are based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python, I am attempting what would be a conditional mutate in R DPLYR.
In short I would like to create a new column in the Data-frame called Result where : if `df.['test']` is greater than 1 `df.['Result']` equals the respective `df.['count']` for that row, if it lower than 1 then `df.['Result']` is

```
df.['count'] *df.['test']
```

I have tried `df['Result']=df['test'].apply(lambda x: df['count'] if  x >=1 else ...)` Unfortunately this results in a series, I have also attempted to write small functions which also return series

I would like the final Dataframe to look like this...

```
no_ Test Count  Result
1   2    1      1
2   3    5      5
3   4    1      1
4   6    2      2
5   0.5  2      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Test'] > 1, df['Count'], df['Count'] * df['Test'])
```

Output:

```
   No_  Test  Count  Result
0    1   2.0      1     1.0
1    2   3.0      5     5.0
2    3   4.0      1     1.0
3    4   6.0      2     2.0
4    5   0.5      2     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work it out with lists comprehensions:

```
df['Result'] = [ df['count'][i] if df['test'][i]>1 else 
                 df['count'][i] * df['test'][i] 
                 for i in range(df.shape[0]) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Test', 'Count'], 
                  data={'Test':[2, 3, 4, 6, 0.5], 'Count':[1, 5, 1, 2, 2]})

df['Result'] = df['Count']
df.loc[df['Test'] < 1, 'Result'] = df['Test'] * df['Count']
```

Output:

```
       Test  Count  Result
0   2.0      1     1.0
1   3.0      5     5.0
2   4.0      1     1.0
3   6.0      2     2.0
4   0.5      2     1.0
```